# How can I keep database synchronized?

Tags: java, database, multithreading

In my case, I need keep the number of users in every role can not exceed certain customized limit. 
How can I program in java?  In my mind, I want to keep add or delete a user into database as synchronized to avoid to threads read the number of users and add or delete a user at same time. But Is it good to keep a long task synchronized ?

```
 synchronized　boolean addUser(UserVo vo){
    Connection connect = db.getConnection();
    String sql = generateSql(vo);
    int number = connect.query("select count(*) from users where role='supermanager';") //long time, syncronized
    if(number > limit){
      return false;
    }
    connect.insert(sql);//long time, synchronized
    connect.close();
 }
```

Comment: synchronizing just on the methods will not help as addUser and deleteUser may happen concurrently.  If the number of users is not so great then I would consider keeping `all users` or `supermanager object` in memory and syncrhonizing access to that List